# Can I start off Cyber Safety seminar by stunning the audience, like getting into their phone's Wifi/Bluetooth to access a folder and show them?

Tags: wifi, bluetooth

I am delivering a lecture on Cyber-safety Basics. I want to start off a lecture by involving the audience to get their attention.

Example: I want to ask everyone to connect their cell phones to a Wifi hotspot and then get into one of the smartphone and extract a file and show it on the projector. That way I will get their attention.

Can anyone please recommend me a way to do this or any other short trick with Wifi/Bluetooth to stun the audience. It's only for lecture purposes. I have a software "Wireless Network Watcher" which gets the MAC addresses of the devices connected to the same Wifi, but that's not very stunning (I believe) to get the attention.

Any help/link will be appreciated.

Comment: sure, but use a stooge to stay ethical.

Comment: If you're giving the lecture, shouldn't you already know about the vulnerabilities you're going to tell them how to protect against?

Comment: No Sir, I do not have that much knowledge in Network Security field. I am basically in the programming side so I had to take some help here. Hope you may understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hacking into someone's device without their consent is illegal (in most places), regardless of whether you have good intentions. Two alternatives:

1) Something with the flavor of social engineering is probably a lot more relevant to a general talk about cyber security, a lot easier to pull off, and not illegal.

For example, put a QR code on your handouts promising a coupon to a local restaurant or a free cup of coffee. Instead of giving them that, have it [redirect to a website like this](http://mybrowserinfo.com/detail.asp) that displays browser and geo-IP info. Have someone with a smartphone scan the code and tell the group what they see... be sure to point out that this could have been a webpage with a zero-day exploit or a phishing website asking you to login to your google account to continue.

2) There are lots of Youtube videos showing phones or laptops being hacked at events like DEFCON.

Comment: To add to the last one, the guy who wrote the Snoopy framework, when he presented it at DEFCON, showed a map of what places the audience came from, by the WiFi probes they were leaking. That's a good demo because they leak that info anyway, and this builds awareness